# Injecting the repository classes in a Custom Action Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a custom action filter attribute that checks if the user has it's service active and if not the filter automatically redirect the user to a renew page.

Recently we did a re-enginering of our code and we introduced the repository pattern. Before of this we used the repository classes directly in the custom action filter like

```
private OrderRepository _orderRepository = new OrderRepository();
```

I am guessing which is the right way to inject repository classes inside the custom action filter now that we are using this pattern.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following blog post from the authoritative source: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. Does the code in the article you referenced works only with Unity? I am using StructureMap in my project. Also can I have constructor injection or should I work with Setter Injection?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with either of those IOCs but I'm sure they are more or less interchangeable. Also, as far as I know constructor vs setter injection is a matter of preference. But feel free to drop Brad a line in the comments section of his blog to see what he thinks.

Answer (score 1):

Brad Wilson shares how to do this:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. Does the code in the article you referenced works only with Unity? I am using StructureMap in my project..